# Special characters in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, special-characters, helper

I would like to have a multiple sign '**×**' inside a link_to helper in my Rails 3 app.

Straightforward code <`%= link_to '&times;', model, :confirm => 'Sure?', :method => :delete %>` outputs `&times;`on my page. How to fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To prevent your string from being "made safe" by Rails' output buffer:

```
<%= link_to '&times;'.html_safe, model, :confirm => 'Sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

**Footnote**

In my own pages, I encode everything as UTF-8, which means that I can use the real Unicode characters directly, rather than use the &...; code, but this probably isn't an option for you if you didn't start your project with that intent.